# sleekxmpp pubsub example

Tags: python, xmpp, publish-subscribe

I am looking for a working example code for implementing SleekXMPP XEP 60 plugin.
What i am trying to do is 
authenticate over TLS and subscribe to a node called "blogupdates"
Then simply wait for events and get the data contained in 
I have searched a few days but I can't find a good working example google or SO

note that I am not subscribing to user but a node so the publisher can be anybody.

any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at this thread on the SleekXMPP mailing list ([Beginner - SleekXMPP - XEP-0060](http://groups.google.com/group/sleekxmpp-discussion/browse_thread/thread/9893daf480fe9c60/c954b17616f2d05b?lnk=gst&q=pubsub%20client#c954b17616f2d05b)) I have an example Pubsub client you can experiment with and examine. I'll be tidying up and polishing those two scripts to add to the bundled examples shortly.

(EDIT: These files are now in the examples directory in the develop branch. See [examples/pubsub_client.py](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/blob/develop/examples/pubsub_client.py) and [examples/pubsub_events.py](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/blob/develop/examples/pubsub_events.py))

For your use case, you'd do:

```
xmpp['xep_0060'].subscribe('pubsub.example.com', 'blogupdates')
```

For more advanced usage, you can also pass:

```
bare=False
# Subscribe using a specific resource, and not the bare JID

subscribee='somejid@example.com'
# Subscribe a different JID to the node, if authorized

options=data_form
# Provide subscription options using a XEP-0004 data form
```

However, if you are using the develop branch, I've added some newer features you may like to make it easier to deal with publish events:

```
# Generic pubsub event handlers for all nodes
xmpp.add_event_handler('pubsub_publish', handler)
xmpp.add_event_handler('pubsub_retract', handler)
xmpp.add_event_handler('pubsub_purge', handler)
xmpp.add_event_handler('pubsub_delete', handler)

# Use custom-named events for certain nodes, in this case 
# the User Tune node from PEP.
xmpp['xep_0060'].map_node_event('http://jabber.org/protocol/tune', 'user_tune')
xmpp.add_event_handler('user_tune_publish', handler)
# ...
# The same suffixes as the pubsub_* events.
# These events are raised in addition to the pubsub_* events.
```

For the event handlers, you can follow the pattern:

```
def pubsub_publish(self, msg):
    # An event message could contain multiple items, but we break them up into
    # separate events for you to make it a bit easier.
    item = msg['pubsub_event']['items']['item']
    # Process item depending on application, like item['tune'], 
    # or the generic item['payload']
```

You can look at the XEP-0107 and related PEP plugins to see more examples, since these features were added to implement those.

So, here is what your use case would look like:

```
# Note that xmpp can be either a ClientXMPP or ComponentXMPP object.
xmpp['xep_0060'].map_node_event('blogupdates', 'blogupdates')
xmpp['xep_0060'].add_event_handler('blogupdates_publish', blogupdate_publish)
xmpp['xep_0060'].subscribe('pubsub.example.com', 'blogupdates')
# If using a component, you'll need to specify a JID when subscribing using:   
# ifrom="specific_jid@yourcomponent.example.com"

def blogupdate_publish(msg):
    """Handle blog updates as they come in."""
    update_xml = msg['pubsub_event']['items']['item']['payload']
    # Do stuff with the ElementTree XML object, update_xml
```

And finally, if you find yourself spending too much time searching on Google, please drop by the Sleek chatroom: sleek@conference.jabber.org

-- Lance

Comment: thank you so much. I am getting some idea now. I will give this a try today and ofcourse be haunting the jabber chatroom now that I know where to find you guys ^^. Definitely could use your polished script for pubsub, mainly as a client sub as that is most useful in python related development where we want to replace MQ with XMPP, I think this will become a major use case in near future. thanks again

Comment: it works but in the release version which i installed via pip I have the same https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/issues/149 . :( thanks anyway

Comment: Ah, yes. The 1.0 release on PyPI is several months old and there have been quite a few bugs fixed, like the one you pointed out. We've been waiting for a bit of development to finish with some plugins, but we may just go ahead and make a release very soon to get those bug fixes out.

Comment: awesome. I'll try to use the develop branch. I am assuming my code from release version will work on develop as well as I did not see any changes to the classes and method structure. Thanks a lot, sleek is an awesome library.

Comment: wanted to post an update. Lance was very helpful , thank you Lance, get his hep in the jabber conf. secondly everything worked perfectly well with the develop branch. I am happy that this project exists.